# How to get azure portal login name in Azure data factory pipeline stored procedure activity

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I need assistance. I am using Azure Data Factory activity for data migration from source to destination. Next, we also need to log the user running these Azure Data Factory pipelines, such as the get portal.azure.com login from azure function, and pass output of azure function to the Azure Data Factory pipeline stored procedure activity and log in to the target database.

At the workflow activity level, I don't see the option to get the portal login username or email id. So I decided to use an Azure function to get the portal username, pass it to the Pipelines activity, and log it to the target log table. But below azure function code return nothing as output.

Can you please suggest if there is anything i am missing in below code to get user or is there any other way to get user information in pipelines activities?

[image]

[image]

Thanks for help...

Comment: I can see your returning `username` directly, try returning it as http response.
Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-csharp?tabs=azure-cli,in-process) documentation.

Comment: Its same returning empty.

Answer (score 0):

In azure function itself just return the username in http response to get the output.

While returning add code below.

```
return  new  OkObjectResult(userName);
```

This will return username.

[image]

Below is my function code.

```
using  System;
using  System.IO;
using  System.Threading.Tasks;
using  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using  Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using  Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using  Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using  Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace  Company.Function

{

public  static  class  userdetails

{

[FunctionName("userdetails")]

public  static  async  Task<IActionResult> Run(

[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route  =  null)] HttpRequest  req,ILogger  log)

{

log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

string  name  =  req.Query["name"];
string  requestBody  =  await  new  StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
dynamic  data  =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
 name  =  name  ??  data?.name;
string  responseMessage  =  string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)?"This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.":  $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";
return  new  OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
}
}
}
```

Later you can use this function URL in ADF web activity to get the data.

Comment: Did tried by using OkObjectResult(userName) but same not returning anything. above code is working fine with simple http request but failing by using clain identity to get portal login user instead of request header.

I am dropping this approach and will call pipeline from  simple .net user interface with login screen and capture user interface login to capture executed by as dont see any other alternate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Activity Logs REST API : Activity Logs – List to get the User ID details.

MSFT docs :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/activity-logs/list?tabs=HTTP

You can use web activity to trigger the REST API

refer my blog for additional details:

https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2023/05/18/automated-way-to-get-the-id-of-user-manually-triggering-the-azure-data-factory-pipeline/